# Where is design time value defined for localized strings in WP8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, localization

When I bind a `TextBlock.Text` to `LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle`, at design time it displays 'MY APPLICATION'. I searched through the code and couldn't find where this string literal is defined, or generally, how do I define design time value for localized strings?

Comment: `AppResources.resx` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localized string resources is saved in `AppResources.resx`. And it is used in design time as well as in run time.

You can edit the `.resx` file in VS to add localized string values :

[image]

Practical reason for separating the resources in `.resx` file is, you can add string resources for other locale by simply adding another `.resx` file with corresponding culture info code suffix.

Further reference : [How to build a localized app for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)